# Maven release plugin : Releasing with a SNAPSHOT version

Tags: java, maven-2, hudson, maven-release-plugin

I know, its not a good practice to release a project with SNAPSHOT dependencies.

But, I would like to know, Is there any way, we can make maven release plugin to release with SNAPSHOT dependencies?

Is there any parameters that I can pass to the maven release plugin to accept SNAPSHOT version of the dependencies while releasing?

Like

```
-Dallow.snapshots= true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider using the `allowTimestampedSnapshots` option to [`release:prepare`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html).  This was apparently added to deal with use-cases where SNAPSHOT dependencies are unavoidable.

But you should only do this if it is unavoidable.  Among other things, some Maven repositories can be configured to automatically delete old SNAPSHOT releases.  If that happened, your released artifacts could end up with permanently broken dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want that? A released version is supposed to never change. Updating one of the snapshot dependencies risks breaking the system. I see two approaches:

Either you have control over the source code of your dependencies, in which case I recommend you to go through the, albeit tedious, process of releasing those projects.

If you don't control the source code you can still rename the binary and manually upload it to your release server. You might still take this approach even for projects under your control, although I strongly encourage you not to.

Comment: I understand that, but is there a way where we can circumvent this while using the release plugin?